# Mean squared logarithmic error using pytorch

Tags: pytorch

hello I'm new with `PyTorch` and i would like to use Mean squared logarithmic error as a loss function in my neural  network for training my DQN agent but i can't find the MSLE in the `nn.functional` in `PyTorch` what the best way to implement it ?

Comment: There's no built in function. An implementation is available [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/rmsle-loss-function/67281/2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well is not hard to do it
the MSLE equation as the photo below shows [image]

now, as some user on the PyTorch [form](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/rmsle-loss-function/67281) suggested

you can be added as a class like this

```
class RMSLELoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mse = nn.MSELoss()
        
    def forward(self, pred, actual):
        return torch.sqrt(self.mse(torch.log(pred + 1), torch.log(actual + 1)))
```

then you can call it normally

```
criterion = RMSLELoss()

rmsle = criterion(pred, actual)
```